# Complex Analysis Problem regarding holomorphic funtions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a domain containing the closer of the unit disk, such that $|f(z)|\leq 5$ on $|z|=1$ then if $f(0)=3+4i$ find $f'(0)$

Hint, please. can I determine the exact form of the function? By using Rouche's theorem I can only say that $f$ a zero inside the unit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Maximum modulus principle.

Comment: I think I got it. that function is eventually constant?

Comment: Yes. I hope you understand why this is the case.

Comment: By the problem we can say in a neighborhood of $0$ the function also attains the maximum which is only possible if f is constant.. am I right?

Comment: Well, yes. I would write it like this: $f$ is continuous so $|f|$ must have a maximum on the compact set $\{|z|\leq 1\}$. But if it wasn't constant then this maximum would have to be only on the boundary $\{|z|=1\}$, because the modulus of a non-constant holomorphic function can't have a maximum in the open unit disk. However, $|f(0)|\geq |f(z)|$ for all $z$ on the boundary.